# API Controller Post, Put and Delete routing not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, restful-url

I am working with asp.net restful services and created WebApi Controller.
it works perfectly with Get but not working with Post, Put Delete.

```
 public string Get()
        {
            return "value";
        }

 public string Post()
        {
            return "value";
        }
```

Routing Configuration

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

http://localhost:50089/api/UserProfile/get
http://localhost:50089/api/UserProfile/Post
```

Post is not working but get is working, I try to add route on top but it doesn't work

Comment: You can try to use the `[HttpPost]` attribute on your method.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work

Comment: You must use the verb POST in the header to get the message routed to your Post() function. Use test client 'google advanced rest client'.

Comment: Well POST isn't a HTTP header but it is http verb thats a part of the message format. 

 This should be your URL you make requests to http://localhost:50089/api/UserProfile, but the different verbs you use will be POST and GET

Comment: Which version of WebAPI are you using?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code, but I think you're calling the wrong URL. Try making a POST request to [http://localhost:50089/api/UserProfile](http://localhost:50089/api/UserProfile) and see if you get a response. 
But if you want the action name to be specified in the URL like in MVC, which I wouldn't recommend, you'll have to change the route template to include {action}.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult MyPostMethod(string param)
    {
       ...
       return Ok();
    }
```

Also, you should return a [IHttpActionResult](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results):

> The IHttpActionResult interface was introducted in Web API 2. Essentially, it defines an HttpResponseMessage factory. Here are some advantages of using the IHttpActionResult interface:
>
> •Simplifies unit testing your controllers.
>
> •Moves common logic for creating HTTP responses into separate classes.
>
> •Makes the intent of the controller action clearer, by hiding the low-level details of constructing the response.

To test, you can use ['poster'](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/poster/) add-on for Firefox.

Comment: "You should return a IHttpActionResult"? That's a strong statement to make. Can you back that up with some documentation?

Comment: More doc and a link added